Upgraded to VS 2022 and SSIS ADO.Net connections no longer work
I have upgraded from VS2019 to VS2022 and none of my ADO.NET connection mangers no longer work. My previous connections in VS2019 were SQLClient Data Provider. When I try and use those same connection managers in VS 2022 I get prompted with

"Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.  Keyword not supported: "Provider Name"

(see screenshot).
When I try and change the connection to Microsoft SQLClient Data Provider the Test Connection validates, but I get an error msg when I try and execute a task of

"Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permission on this connection."

Again, these connections worked fine with VS2019.


In my experience, you will have to re-install the SSDT extension for Visual Studio. Even VS product updates within a major version seem to break the SSDT extension from time to time.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled SSDT as well as SSIS and still get the error msg.  I have an open ticket with MS, but they don't seem to have a solution either.   I've been stuck on this for days :(

May be related to System.Data.SqlClient being deprecated. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/announcement-system-data-sqlclient-package-is-now-deprecated/ba-p/4227205. Are you able to use .Net Providers for OleDb\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server?

This is an issue with VS version out of sync with the Extensions.
Please see the fix found here. https://community.zappysys.com/t/ssis-ado-net-connection-error-keyword-not-supported-providername/394
It helped me.
